# Generate HTML tag with more than one attribute in SQL request

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Could you please help me to understand how can I generate XML/HTML with more than one attribute

I have this SQL code

```
select
    [td/@align] = 'center', td = format(GETDATE(),'dd.MM.yyyy'), null
for xml path('tr')
```

This code returns as its result:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">16.09.2020</td>
</tr>
```

and I need

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="background-color: red;">16.09.2020</td>
</tr>
```

Can't find out how to do this...

If I try to use something like this `[td/@align/@style]` - SQL is causing an error

> Column name 'td/@align/@style' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '@'(0x0040) is the first character at fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
select 'center' AS [td/@align]
       ,'background-color: red;'  AS [td/@style]
       ,format(GETDATE(),'dd.MM.yyyy') AS [td]       
for xml path('tr')
```

it yields this:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="background-color: red;">16.09.2020</td>
</tr>
```

You can think of one row columns as xml tag value and attributes, which are grouped using the alias `AS`. So, for more attributes, just add new value with the corresponding alias - `td/@...`.

Comment: I would, however, personally use `CONVERT` and a style code over `FORMAT`. `FORMAT` tends to be pretty slow when used against larger data sets.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's very good point - `FORMAT` should be used if `CONVERT`/`CAST` cannot do the job.